# Modal slider with React

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-modal, slide, image-gallery

I am not thinking clearly here and I would like some help. I think I am overcomplicating things.
I want to copy the functionality that you can see in https://unsplash.com/ when clicking an image , which is the ability to go back and forward in the array of pictures and I am doing clumsy mistakes with the props.
So far I have the grid of images and the modal that pops up when you click each image. Now, I cant go forward.

My code looks like

```
const HomePage = () => {
  
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
 

  useEffect(() => {
    getData();
  }, []);

  const getData = () => {
    axios.get(api).then((res) => {setData([...data, ...res.data])}).catch((err) => {
        alert("error");
      });
   
  };



  return (
    <>
      
          {data.map((item,idx) => (
            <Image
              url={item.urls.regular}
              user={item.user}
              key={idx}
              id={item.id}
            />
          ))}
        </div>
```

Cool, I get the array with the data. Perfect, then lets go to Image component =>

```
const Image = ({ url, user, id }) => {
  const [currentImg, setCurrentImg] = useState("");
  const [show, setShow] = useState(false);
  

  const handleClose = () => setShow(false);

  const showModal = (id) => {
    fetch(`https://api.unsplash.com/photos/${id}?client_id=client_id`)
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => {
        setCurrentImg(data.urls.regular);
        setShow(true);
      });
  };

  return (
    <>
    
      <img
        onClick={() => showModal(id)}
        src={url}
        alt=""
      />

      <Modal show={show} onHide={handleClose}> // somewhere inside this modal will go Prev & Next buttons

        <Modal.Header closeButton>
          <Modal.Title>{user.name}</Modal.Title>
        </Modal.Header>

        <Modal.Body>
          <img width="100%" src={currentImageUrl} alt="" />
        </Modal.Body>

      </Modal>
    <>
```

As you can see, if I do click I get a popup with the image because I get the modal with the ID, but first of all, I don’t think that is a good solution to make a call again to the api, but most important, is that I don’t figure how to built a simple solution to the future Next and Previous button.
I have seen some packages that could help me (eg. react light box), but I want to learn the logic!
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a carousel in the modal and then slide through the pictures.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).